# Change constructor order of operations?

Tags: c++

I have the following sample code, and the copy assignment is doing something I don't want - it's first constructing the new samp(6), then copying it to z, then destroying the new samp(6) it built. Is there a way to change the constructors such that = acts like a pointer, destroying the originally constructed samp(5) and replacing it with the new samp(6), calling the destructor on samp(5), rather than samp(6)?

```
#include <iostream>
class samp
{
public:
    samp(int a)
    {
        m_a = a;
        std::cout << "cons" <<m_a << std::endl;
    }
    int m_a;

    samp(const samp& other)
    {
        std::cout << "copy" << m_a << std::endl;
        m_a = other.m_a;
    }
    samp& operator= (const samp& other)
    {
        std::cout << "assg" << m_a << std::endl;
        samp* z =new samp(other.m_a);
        return *z;

    }
    ~samp()
    {
        std::cout << "dest" <<m_a<< std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    samp z(5);
    z = samp(6);
    std::cout << z.m_a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious what you are trying to gain from doing this instead of a regular move assingnment.

Comment: Would a move assignment do it? There's a thing in the old object I need the destructor to do something with, and for it not to get copied.

Comment: *and the copy assignment is doing something I don't want* -- No, it is doing something that you wrote.  The default copy-assignment will do exactly what it's supposed to do.  You stepped in for some reason and decided to take over and do weird stuff.

Comment: Ergo the question - is there a way to make it do the thing I do want?

Comment: Honestly, copy assignment and copy constructors shouldn't be used for business logic.  They should be there for one reason and one reason only -- to make copies.  The compiler will be calling these functions in places you won't expect, and that code you've written will be invoked.

Comment: Ah, this kind of cleverness is a bad idea?

Comment: @ProbablyAStupidQuestion The underlying problem here is your assignment operator is not implemented correctly. It should delete the previously held ressource, and it should not allocate a new `samp`. I can't imagine a scenario where `samp* z =new samp(other.m_a);` is the right thing to do in a copy assignment operator. If you can't copy the underlying resource, you should *not* implement a copy assignment operator (delete it). In any case, you should implement a move assignment operator.

Comment: Yes, it is a bad idea.  Unless you were implementing some sort of reference counted object, you're risking having the assignment operator being called by the compiler, and thus "fake copies" will be floating around your app and you won't know it.  These types of bugs are very hard to find and diagnose.  Either don't write your own, or if you do, make sure its job is kept to making copies, i.e. if you have two objects, and one is a copy of the other, whatever you do with object 1, the behavior better be the same if you had used object 2.

Comment: Yeah I think that's the better way to go, put a reference counter on the thing I need to keep track of. Easy to implement too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`operator=` is a member of your object so the `this` pointer is available. Also, assignment means the target of the assignment should change. Your version is creating a new object, but leaving the target alone. See if this does what you want:

```
samp& operator= (const samp& other)
{
    m_a = other.m_a;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: nope, I was expecting dest5, but I'm not sure this is a good idea anymore.

Comment: What's "dest5"?

Comment: the output when the samp with 5 in it is destructed (destroyed?)

Comment: But your code says you're assigning `samp(6)` to it. If you're changing the meaning of "assignment" for this object, then your code will be very difficult to maintain.

Comment: Thus why I think it's a bad idea now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe pointer semantics is what you want:

```
#include <memory>

// ...

    auto z = std::make_unique<samp>(5);
    z = std::make_unique<samp>(6);   // dest5

    std::cout << z->m_a << '\n';     // 6
```

Although if you are coming to C++ from a language where object names are object references,  it may be better to get used to C++ value semantics instead of trying to replicate object references :)

Comment: Probably I've spent the most time in the functional languages, where this distinction is less essential.